# no data from json_decode

Tags: parsing, hyperlink, json

I need to parse article links from

> http://blog.tecnologiaqueinteressa.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/Virtualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999

The problem is that json_decode returns no data. I tried:

```
$url = 'http://blog.tecnologiaqueinteressa.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/Virtualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999';

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($html, true);
var_dump ($json);
```

$json is just NULL.
I want to know how can i decode the json, so i can parse article links.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The response is not valid json, it is jsonp ( padded json ). In order to parse this in php, you must first remove the padding.

This means, you must remove

```
// API callback
pageNavi(
```

from the beginning, and

```
);
```

from the end of the response. After that, you can decode the string.